# Why do I get "Invalid Data Source" when opening a GPX file from ETrex 30?

Tags: qgis, google-maps-api, gpx

Why is it if i load the .gpx files in qgis it says "Invalid Data Source" as well as in google maps?

I want to view the waypoints from the .gpx file. I used gpx etrex 30

Comment: Can you share the GPX file? GPX files should read just fine in QGIS. Also, what did you use to create / download the GPX file?

Answer (score 1):

You need to use `GPS Tools`. You can find it from `Vector -> GPS -> GPS Tools`. From GPS Tools you can load the gpx data, as you can see below:

[image]

Comment: GPS tools isn't necessary - the "Add vector layer" dialogue works without need for the plugin. Also, in your screenshot you are showing the "GPX Conversions" tab, not "load GPX file" which is what OP would need.

Comment: @Simbamangu Thanks for your comment, I updated my answer to use Load GPX File. The OP has a problem in loading gpx file into QGIS. He didn't mention whether he used 'Add Vector File' or any thing else. but I assumed he used 'Add Vector File' and he got Invalid Source problem. I just gave him alternative solution.